# How to update the compatible tags in `pip` in `conda` environments?

Tags: pip, conda, miniconda

I tried to install a custom package through `pip` in a conda environment for python 3.9 (created using miniconda by `conda create -n py39 python=3.9`). When I run `pip install -i <custom index> my_package`, it would fail. However, when I revert to native python in MacOSX, I can install it successfully.

In conda environment `py39`: When I look at the output of `pip install -vv -i <custom index> my_package`, I can see `pip` was looking through the available wheels from `<custom_index>` and all of them failed to match the compatible tags listed in `pip debug --verbose`.

In native python 3.9: the output of `pip install -vv -i <custom index> my_package` indicates that it found a match for the wheel tag `cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_universal2`.

Obviously my system supports the package, because native python `pip` managed to install it, but somehow `pip` in conda environment does not include the tag. In fact, the `pip` in conda environment only supports tags up to `macosx_10_16`, which is quite old. Is there a way to update the compatible tags?

In the conda environment, I tried doing `python3 -c "import packaging.tags; print(list(packaging.tags.sys_tags()))"`, and from the output I can see `cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_universal2`, that means `pip` should also accept that tag, isn't that right?

Comment: Is your miniconda x64 or arm64?

Comment: my miniconda is x64. `sysconfig.get_platform()` shows `'macosx-10.9-x86_64'`